# How to open two frames that share the same code in java?

Tags: java, jframe

I was wondering how to open two frames using the same code, but work on the code independently. I am making a two players game and I do not want one player's frame to affect the others. I would however like one integer to be shared among them, if not complicated.

Just to  make it easier, whenever you start a program twice on java, each window is separate from the other but still uses the same code. I basically want the same thing when I open the programe ONCE, so that they open side by side.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-or-bad-practice

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear about what you are saying but this is what I understand

- Need a java program which invokes two different frames and display same integer value

and would do this as follows

- Create a main class with a static integer declaration
- Create a class for frame and init the objects that are required and write actions/event listeners for components
- User integer from main class wherever necessary
- create objects as part of psvm(String a[]) and initialize the frames

Comment: Yes. The integer part is not really necessary, as it is just needed to keep track of score. I also already have a class containing the useful code for one player.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create 2 objects of this class?

Comment: Doesn't work, they will share the code simultaneously.